# PrimeNg-Button : button not showing fa icon if label is not provided

Tags: angular, button, primeng

I want to show button with icon and without label. 
and i am trying with this

```
<button type="text" pButton icon="fa-angle-left"></button>
```

but it is not showing fa icon, and displaying blank button.
if i try giving label, then it will show icon as well as label.

don't know if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**First**: Make sure to import the *ButtonModule* to your component module (*or just AppModule*) like with:

```
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng';
```

**Second**: Add the *ButtonModule* to the *imports Array* like this for example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ButtonModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

**Finally**: Create your desired button with this code:

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="count()" icon="fa-angle-left"></button>
```

Try all that here:
https://embed.plnkr.co/GEpcJG/

**NB:** I supposed that you have no other problems with ***primeng*** in general.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this problem by overwriting one parameter in css for class "ui-button-icon-only":

```
.ui-button-icon-only {
  text-indent: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this with 2.0.Final of primeng and it's totally working.

```
<button pButton type="text" icon="fa-close"></button>
```

Comment: I have updated my primeng by reinstalling by using this command "npm install primeng" but still no luck.

Comment: npm install primeng@latest --save  and try sass -w resources --sourcemap=none

Comment: what is this "sass -w resources --sourcemap=none" ? i dont know about this. can u explain me where to do that?

Comment: After you wrote sass or scss file you are running this command and it's automatically convert it to the css files. In your folder for example styles folder you have scss or sass file inside of that folder you can run this command.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue
actually it was because of jquery ui css. it was overriding ui-button-icon-only class.
so as of now i have removed jquery-ui.css file and now button showing icons.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just added the ***ButtonModule*** from PrimeNG and voila, it works!

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, import the Button Module, like this :

```
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
```

Second add it to imports :

```
imports: [ ButtonModule ]
```